# Good approach for determining visible subviews in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, lazy-loading

I'm trying to find the best approach for determining the visible subviews in a `UIScrollView`, I already found a good approach and it is: When the `UIScrollView` is scrolled I iterate over the array of subviews in my `UISCrollView` then find out whether each subview is visible or not by checking if the subview's frame intersects with the scrollview boundaries, I also cache the max offset that the scrollview has reached so the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method doesn't get called more than once at the same offset. I use this code for this approach:

```
CGFloat currentXOfsset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;

if (currentXOfsset > maxScrolledXOffset) {

    for (UIView *subview in scrollView.subviews) {

        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButtonWithImageURL class]] && CGRectIntersectsRect(scrollView.bounds, subview.frame)) {

            //Do whatever you want with the visible subviews.
        }
    }
}

maxScrolledXOffset = currentXOfsset>maxScrolledXOffset?currentXOfsset:maxScrolledXOffset;
```

This works properly, but the only problem here is that I have to loop through all the subviews when the `UIScrollView` scrolls, and that makes the scroll quite unsmooth, because I load images in these subviews.

What are the other approaches that I can use for determining visible subviews but with keeping a smooth scroll?

Comment: Wait why is this logic even here?

Comment: Read the question again please. And never mind about that logic in the middle. It is not related to the question, I just forgot to remove it.

Comment: And if you are wondering about that `[subview isKindOfClass:[UIButtonWithImageURL class]]` it is here because in addition to the subviews that you added yourself to the `UIScrollView`, there are other subviews that are automatically added by the `UIScrollView`, so I have to specify the class in order not to mess the `UIScrollView` and get only the desired result. And `CGRectIntersectsRect(scrollView.bounds, subview.frame` is surely here to determine if that subview is visible on the `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct approach. How many subviews do you have in this scrollView? On which device is it slow? You may be doing another heavy operation somewhere (post more code so we can figure that out).

If you had a lot of subviews, a faster way would be to use an algorithm that reduce the number of views to test, like a quad tree or a static grid. I'm positive that this will be definitely overkill for you. CGRectIntersectsRect only does up to 4 float comparisons.

Comment: 15 subviews, it is not slow, it is just a little unsmooth, it really doesn't matter because it works correctly and it is not very catchy to see. But I just wondered how the some apps do more than this and it is perfectly smooth.  Maybe I should check my code because as you said there are other processes which are running at the same time. And sorry I did not understand the last line, what does it mean that it only does up to 4 float comparisons?

Comment: "if (x < y)" is a floating point comparison if x or y is a floating point number (CGFloat for instance). Can you share exactly what you do in the "Do whatever you want with the subviews"?